# Best method to download HTTPs files in R for an R Package

Tags: r

I'm writing an R package where I have to download a fairly large file (7gb, 4gb compressed) from AWS to be able to run it properly. I've seen some posts on here for people using RCurl and downloader, but nothing seemed to be suitable for this job. The traditional download.files might be fine, and then I might couple it with unzip(), but will the popup be shown to the user? It would be nice to have a progress bar instead, or something along those lines.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I use `download.file()` and `unzip()` in a function of a team internal package. It shows a progress bar in the console. The file I am downloading is much smaller though. `data.table::fread()` might be another option to check out, it has an option for a progress bar.